# Laravel: Class not found if it is called from a Trait

Tags: laravel, controller, traits

After creating several Apps with Laravel and using softDelete properties I realized that methods like destroy(), restore() and kill() are exactly the same among several controllers. Therefore I am trying to put themn in a trait and use it from diferent Controllers.

My code is as follows:

**ProfilesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Profile;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{

    public function destroy(Profile $profile)
    {
        Profile::del($profile, 'profiles');
        return redirect()->route('profiles.index');
    }

    public function trashed()
    {
        Profile::trash('Profile');
    }
}
```

**Profile.php** (model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Profile extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'role_id', 'title', 'subtitle', 'slug', 'birthday', 'about'];

    use SoftDeletes, Helpers, commonMethods;

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
    // ... more code here 
}
```

trait file: **commonMethods.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Profile;
use Session;

trait commonMethods
{

    public static function del($element, $page_name)
    {
        $element->delete();
        Session::flash('success', $element . ' successfully deleted!');
    }

    public static function trash($model)
    {
        $total = $model::onlyTrashed()->get();
        $total_tr = count($total);
        $all_tr = $model::all();

        return view('partials.templates.trashed', compact('total', 'total_tr', 'all_tr'));
    }

// ...more code here 
}
```

**The problem:**

- I try to visit the view "Trashed" that will list all elements "softdeleted" but not "killed", the method.
- I pass the $model variable with the method trash($model)
- I get the following error:
  *Class App/Profile does not found. Try to call App/Profile*

I have debugged and the $model variable contains exactly what I need, the string 'Profile' which is what I need to build the Query:

```
$total = Profile::onlyTrashed()->get();
```

This query works while in the ProfilesController, but does not work while in a trait, since the model class is not found.

**Any idea how could I make it work?**

I am using Laravel 6.

Comment: have you verified the namespace ?

Comment: ProfilesController.php file I think you missed to use `use App\Profile`

Comment: Yes I have verified the namespace. I did not included here to save space. I edit the question

Comment: `Profile` or `Profiles`?

Comment: Profile. Models are singular (Profile.php), Controllers plural (ProfilesController.php)

Comment: your question says "$model variable contains exactly what I need, the string 'Profiles' " ... so that is supposed to be `Profile`?.

Comment: Is "Profile" in singular I explained it wrongly. I edit the question

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a class as a string you will want to use its full name. `'App\Profile'` instead of `'Profile'`.

```
$model = 'Profile';
new $model; // will use `\Profile`

$model = 'App\Profile';
new $model; // will use '\App\Profile';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have a look into it, I am not in front of the computer now

Answer (score 0):

In your controller( ProfilesController ) write :

```
use App\Profile;
```

In your model write  :

```
use App\commonMethods;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have a look into it, I am not in front of the computer now